# Reloading data grid from the method called from cell leave event

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

I have a Datagridview Cell Leave event, from which a method is getting called, in which i reload my grid values, but it seems i cant reload the grid in leave event,

```
private void TestGrid_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)  
{
    int currentCell = TestGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    int oldCell = e.ColumnIndex;
    Loadfinalscreen();
}

public void Loadfinalscreen()
{
    clearGrid();

}
public void clearGrid()
{
    TestGrid.Rows.Clear();
    TestGrid.Columns.Clear();
}
```

It throws me the following exception:

> Operation cannot be performed in this event handler.
>
> System.SystemException {System.InvalidOperationException}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you would do that. But as general advice, anytime you cannot do something inside some event, use deferred execution (which in WF is achieved by `Control.BeginInvoke`). For your case it could be something like this:

```
private void TestGrid_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)  
{
    int currentCell = TestGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    int oldCell = e.ColumnIndex;
    BeginInvoke(new Action(Loadfinalscreen());
}
```

Comment: Still it gives error
       {"Cannot clear this list."}

Comment: Then your grid is using a bound mode. Insert `TestGrid.DataSource = null;` line at the beginning of your `clearGrid` method.